# Get count from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am developing a solution in VS2010 which involves 2 projects. The first project is a normal windows form application with a button which increments an integer variable whenever it is pressed. The other project is a simple web service which returns the value of the variable. I have set the counter as both public and static as follows:

```
public static int count = 0;

private void AddCountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
}

public static int GetCount()
{
    return count;
}
```

The other project has this method:

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetCount()
{
    return MyApplication.Form1.GetCount();
}
```

However, when the above method is called it always returns 0. I was hoping that someone would shed some light on the subject. Thankyou, and have a good day.

Comment: Your two projects are running as two different processes.  One as a windows form, and the other as a web process.  The count defined within your MyApplication.Form1 is not shared between these two processes.

Comment: @Tung: you should write that up as the answer.

Comment: Why are you (swift) using ASMX web services anyway? That's a legacy technology and shouldn't be used for new development.

Comment: It is the only thing I am familiar with. I have read a few articles on REST web services but I've decided to stick with what I know. This is only being used for a simple project, nothing which I plan to distribute to the public. I only need to show a proof of concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two projects are running as two different processes. One as a windows form, and the other as a web process. The count defined within your MyApplication.Form1 is not shared between these two processes.

@John, thank you

Comment: Any idea how I am able to this? It is kind of vital to what I am trying to achieve. I do not think its very good practice to have multiple worker threads which are quite computationally intensive in the background of a web server.

Comment: Hey Swift, what are you computing, and what is the desired lifetime of your **count**? Relying on a static variable that exists as part of a web service probably won't work for most projects, since the value will go away once the worker process gets recycled.  You might want to store the value somewhere else, and use the web service as a way to SET/GET the count

Comment: Basically, the process which is working on **count** increments it with every loop iteration. The webservice is there so that users can get the value of **count** at that moment in time. There are no workers in the web service.

Comment: When someone closes and reopens your winform, do you want **count** to be the value it previously was?  If so, you need to persist that data somewhere, preferably a location that your web service also has access to. A database would be overkill for storing only one value.  You could have your winform write the value to a file, and have your web service read this value from the file.

Comment: Yes that solution did come to mind but I thought even that would be overkill, after all its just a simple integer. I thought that web service could access the winform's memory portion and retrieve the integer's value from there, but I think that would create unnecessary complications such as race conditions. Alright @Tung, thanks for your input. You've been a great help.